# How to migrate Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault to MSAL

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, azure-adal-deprecation

We're trying to migrate a net6.0 console from ADAL to MSAL. After removing packages- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, we're getting compile time errors on AzureServiceTokenProvider, KeyVaultClient and AddAzureKeyVault shown below. How should we replace the following block of code to provide the same functionality but using MSAL packages?

```
MyJobOption jobOption = Configuration.GetSection("MyJobOption").Get<MyJobOption>();
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
// The following line causes CS1061: 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureKeyVault' without the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault package
Configuration = configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
    new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
    {
        Vault = jobOption.KeyVaultUrl,
        Client = keyVaultClient,
        Manager = new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager()
    })
    .Build();
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

Comment: You are probably failing the Authentication or TLS.  Authentication method changed between ADAL and MSAL.  Timeout indicates the connection did not complete.  Often when a connection doesn't complete the error message is erroneous.  Is keyValutClient null or is there a status response like 200 OK?  If null than connection did not complete.  So either the URL is wrong, you do not have a route from client to server, or TLS failed.  What OS are you using on client and server?  TLS usually fails when OS is old or the TLS certificate is not installed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest package for supporting Azure KeyVault configuration source is named `Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets`. Also, for authentication you will need the `Azure.Identity` package. Esure you installed these, and your code for KeyVault configuration will be no more complex than this:

```cs
configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri("<Vault URI>"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```